# Oracle SQL Join with Date

Tags: sql, oracle, data-warehouse

I have following tables:

1. `Dim_Date`
2. `Dim_Prod_Cat`
3. `Fact_Prod_Sales_By_Cat`

I have SQL:

```
Select b.date_key,
       b.day_name_of_week,
       a.name prod_cat_name,
       Sum(nvl(a.total_sales,0))
 From Dim_Date b
 Left Outer Join (Select * 
                   From Fact_Prod_Sales_By Cat sa 
                  Inner Join Dim_Prod_Cat c 
                     On sa.prod_cat_key = c.prod_cat_key) a
   ON a.date_key = b.date_key
Group By a.name,b.date_key
```

Problem is, If there is no sales on let's say Sunday in Fact table, I do not get that record row for that Prod_cat

Dim_Date has all the data worth of dates for 5 years (3 year previous and 2 years future)

Expected:

```
Prod_Cat Week_Day_Name  Sales
-------- -------------  -----------
C1   Monday     1000.00

C1   Tuesday    100.00
...

..

C1  Sunday      0.00 <----

..

..

C2  Monday          1000.00

..

..

C2  Saturday        0.00 <---

C2  Sunday          10000.00

...

..
```

Comment: Did you check that table contains the sunday ? If so and it does, I have seen Oracle screw up, use their own syntax '(+)' rather than ansi join.

Comment: I have edited the response into question

Comment: Do you want to see (i) every date included that is in the dim_date table, or (ii) every date included for which there was a sale under any category at all, or (iii) every date included that is between the first and the last date of sale for all categories?

Comment: Also, what's your Oracle version?

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could show us the attributes of each table too.

From this starter query, one error I found was the use of `d` (that I imagine it should be `b`) and no `d` is defined.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT b.date_key, b.day_name_of_week, a.name, SUM(a.tot)
    FROM Dim_Date b JOIN
        (SELECT c.name, nvl(sa.total_sales,0) AS tot, sa.date_key
            FROM Fact_Prod_Sales_By_Cat sa 
                INNER JOIN Dim_Prod_Cat c ON sa.prod_cat_key = c.prod_cat_key) a
        ON a.date_key = b.date_key
            GROUP BY a.name,b.date_key;
```

Second try:

```
SELECT b.date_key, b.day_name_of_week, a.name, SUM(a.tot)
    FROM Dim_Date b JOIN
        (SELECT c.name, nvl(sa.total_sales,0) AS tot, sa.date_key
            FROM Fact_Prod_Sales_By_Cat sa 
                LEFT JOIN Dim_Prod_Cat c ON sa.prod_cat_key = c.prod_cat_key 
                    GROUP BY sa.date_key) a
        ON a.date_key = b.date_key
            GROUP BY a.name,b.date_key;
```

Comment: Without having the tables attributes, I think your problem is that you should use the `nvl(total_sales,0)` into the `INNER table a`. Making this way, you no longer need a `LEFT JOIN`, since you don't have a `NULL VALUE` into the `TABLE a`.

Comment: problem is that, there may not be records in fact table for some dates.

Comment: Can you make a SQLFiddle so I can test the queries? I understand your statement.

Comment: @gpa Check the second query I wrote. I think this way may go right.

Answer (score 0):

Your simple aggregation query ought to just be:

```
Select   d.day_name_of_week,
         c.name prod_cat_name,
         Sum(f.total_sales)
 From    Dim_Date               d
 Join    Fact_Prod_Sales_By Cat f ON f.date_key     = d.date_key
 Join    Dim_Prod_Cat           c On f.prod_cat_key = c.prod_cat_key
Group By d.day_name_of_week,
         c.name prod_cat_name
```

Based on that, in order to fill the missing days in you can use a partitioned outer join in recent Oracle versions:

```
Select v.prod_cat_name,
       t.day_name_of_week,
       Coalesce(v.total_sales,0) total_sales
from (
    Select   d.day_name_of_week,
             c.name prod_cat_name,
             Sum(f.total_sales) total_sales
     From    Dim_Date               d
     Join    Fact_Prod_Sales_By Cat f ON f.date_key     = d.date_key
     Join    Dim_Prod_Cat           c On f.prod_cat_key = c.prod_cat_key
    Group By d.day_name_of_week,
             c.name prod_cat_name) v
partition by (v.prod_cat_name)
right outer join
 (select distinct day_name_of_week
  FROM   dim_date) t
ON (v.day_name_of_week = t.day_name_of_week);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a Cartesian product (done with a CROSS JOIN clause) for all product categories and dates, then (LEFT!) join it to an aggregated fact table data to get sales amount for what was sold and finally use NVL function to show zeros for non-selling combinations:

```
SELECT
    d.date_key,
    d.day_name_of_week,
    pc.name AS prod_cat_name,
    NVL(f.total_sales, 0) AS total_sales
FROM
    Dim_Date d
CROSS JOIN
    Dim_Prod_Cat pc
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            date_key,
            prod_cat_key,
            SUM(total_sales) AS total_sales
        FROM
            Fact_Prod_Sales_By_Cat
        GROUP BY
            date_key,
            prod_cat_key
    ) f
ON
    d.date_key = f.date_key
AND
    pc.prod_cat_key = f.prod_cat_key;
```